# Xamarin Binding from List, query List in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, xamarin

If´ve got a xaml-view, which gets some values from a list (from a DB throw a rest-service). so there are some parameters like "id", "phone number" or "adress". Evrybody has an ID, sometimes a phoneNo, sometimes Address or both. now i want to view a list, with the ID, but only with "people" which has got an phone number. that for, i´ve got a listview, in which i´m binding the phone number f.e.:

```
 ...<viewcell x:Name="people">
                                    <Label Text="ID: "/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ID}"/>                                        
                                    <Label Text="PhoneNo: "/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding PhoneNr}"/>
  </viewcell>...
```

this is where i set the itemsource:

```
        people.ItemsSource = retList;
```

so, as you can see, i will get a list, where all people are listed, sometimes there are phonenumbers, sometimes this field is empty. but i wonly want the peoble with an phonenumber in my list. is this possible? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

`var phonesList = retList.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PhoneNr)).ToList();`

Comment: ah damn i ha´ve to ask it in a other way: everybody has got a phonenr, but some are german numbers(+49) and some are swiss numbers (+41) for example. so i´ve got an other value which says "pre-number". so i want only the people, where the pre-no is a swiss one

Comment: But the answer will be almost the same except used condition: `var phonesList = retList.Where(p => (p.PhoneNr!= null && p.PhoneNr.StartsWith("(+49)"))).ToList();`. In every case you will obtain a new list based on existing one under some condition. Am I right this is your goal?

Comment: okay thanks a lot. there´s still a little error: in my case, the "phoneNr" is a type of a enum. so it says, there is not the posibility of "StartsWith(...)"

Comment: Yes, `StartsWith` is intended for strings. So you should use something like `...&&  p.PhoneNr == YourDesiredValue`.

Comment: as a string doesnt work.. it´s called Pre_number in my case. so it should be something like: where peoble.pre_number == +49